# C++20 explicitly defaulted equality operator

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, default, c++20, comparison-operators

I'm trying to understand the new default comparison operators introduced in C++20.  My issue is about when an explicitly defaulted comparison operator gets implicitly defined.  The following code example illustrates the question:

```
#include <iostream>

struct B
{
  operator bool() const { return true; }
};

struct D : B
{
  bool operator==(const D&) const = default;
};

bool operator==(B, B) { return false; }

int main ()
{ D d;
  std::cout << (d == d);
}

/* Outputs:
0   in gcc 10.1
1   in msvc 19.26
*/
```

The output of this program is compiler-dependent.  It seems that MSVC defines the operator== for class D when it is encounters the declaration as defaulted, hence it doesn't use the operator== that is defined later for class B. By contrast, gcc waits with the implicit definition of D's  operator== until it is actually needed, by which time the operator== defined for B is in scope, and gets used.  Which behavior, if either, is correct ?

A related question, is why a defaulted operator== can't be declared for a class with reference members ? I could see that reference members could pose a problem  with the MSVC approach, because a reference member might refer to an incomplete type when the defaulting declaration for operator== is encountered. With the gcc approach, the reference's type would always be complete before gcc attempts to define the defaulted operator.

Comment: "*A related question, is why a defaulted operator== can't be declared for a class with reference members ?*" This is not a related question at all.

Answer (score 3):

GCC is wrong here (not unsurprisingly considering its results). When creating the definition of a defaulted comparison operator, [the standard says](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/class.compare.default#1):

> Name lookups in the defaulted definition of a comparison operator function are performed from a context equivalent to its function-body.

And the function body of a defaulted function [is where `= default` is](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/dcl.dcl#dcl.fct.def.default-1). Therefore, the `bool operator==(B, B)` function should not be visible to the function body of the defaulted comparison operator.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  I note the sentence immediately preceding the one you quote says:  A comparison operator function for class C that is defaulted on its first declaration and is not defined as deleted 
is implicitly defined when it is odr-used or needed for constant evaluation.  I guess that would be clearer if when were changed to if.